# WP Query and ACF fields

Tags: php, wordpress

Im new to WP Query and ACF custom fields. I want to write a code that will show first 3 results from the calculation of the total_score custom field. I have managed to short by the total score but I want to show the title and permanlink of the first 3 posts so the visitor will click and go to the post. Any help will be much appreciated. My code so far :

```
$args = array( 
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'post_title'    => true,);
$all_posts = array();
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ):

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ): $the_query->the_post();

            
    // Get all fields
    $fields = get_fields();

    // Push each $fields array into the $all_posts array
    array_push($all_posts, $fields);

endwhile;

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();

// Print the result here and do what you choose
print_r($all_posts);
endif;
if(isset($_POST['place'])) 
{ // start the loop
$q1=$_POST["place"];
//CORECT CODE !!!!  
foreach($all_posts as &$value) {
if ($value['question1']==$q1){
$value['total_score']=$q1;  
}
}   } //end question 1
// question 2
if(isset($_POST['home']))
{ // start the loop
$q2=$_POST["home"];
foreach($all_posts as &$value) {
if ($value['question2']==$q2){
$value['total_score']=$value['total_score']+$q2;
}
//echo $value['total_score']."<br>";    }   
//echo "Q2"."<br>";             
//print_r($all_posts);
} //end question 2
// question 3
if(isset($_POST['hours']))
{ // start the loop
$q3=$_POST["hours"];    

//CORECT CODE !!!!  

foreach($all_posts as &$value) {


if ($value['question2']==$q3){

$value['total_score']=$value['total_score']+$q3;    
}

}   
//echo "Q2"."<br>";             
} //end question 3  
            
// shorting by total_score
function sortByOrder($a, $b) {
return $b['total_score'] - $a['total_score'];
}
usort($all_posts, 'sortByOrder');               
   //print_r($all_posts);   
foreach($all_posts as &$value) {
echo $value['total_score']."<br>";  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please replace your code with only this code. It's give you only 3 post and your total_score ASC or DESC

and Replace data in as per comment

Let me know if any Query

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'portfolio', // your post type name
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', // if total_score is string then use it - meta_value
    'meta_key' => 'total_score', // your meta key name ( total_score custom field )
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'order' => 'ASC' // ASC or DESC

);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    echo '<a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a>';
endwhile;
endif;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Many thanks @Team Dolphin for the code. It seems to work! I will finilize all the total score from form submission by tomorrow and will confirm. you saved me for hours searching!

Comment: I have my question. In my code I want to add the $q1 value in total_score array when submit. How can this acheived?

Comment: Actually I have 15  questions which I store in variables $q1,$q2,q3.. e.t.c. When the form is submited I want to add the values of the $q1, q2.... in the total_score array  and then to have the result of 3 top total_score posts. How can I get this result?

Comment: I don't understand your questions?

Comment: Sorry if I did't explain correctly.My page is https://pet-link.gr/demo-finder. On submit I want to add in a value (total_score) points depending on dropdown selection. It's a matching system so when the user submit the algorith search and brings the best matches depending on the higher scores (top 3).

Answer (score 0):

You could look at using your `$args` variable to both limit and filter the results of WP_Query. Setting your `'posts_per_page' => 3`. This means only 3 posts will be returned in the query.

However, as you are fetching all of the posts and using `usort` to sort them, you can swap this out to use [this resource](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/) to help you query using a custom field. This will reduce the amount of work is needed to compile the posts you require.

You can then use the final result to loop over the 3 posts and output your title & permalink.

Comment: Glen thank you but I don't know how to swap the code with the resource you mentioned. Can you help with adding some.code for the result I want to fetch?

Comment: Also the total_score field is dummy.Does not keep any value. I use it for the array to add values when the form is submitted depending on the value of the drop down list of the form.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Please see the answer by @Team Dolphin  I had the same idea and they have explained it very nicely.